Sequalize ORM. sequalize.sync() success but in pg admin 4 table not created, in Express Typescript
I Trying to Created a Table "Food" using Sequalize ORM, But When i using sequalize.sync(), table cannot created in PG Admin 4. How To Fix This.
I See In Documentation But Not Helping Me
Config.ts
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";


const sequelize = new Sequelize({
database : 'seblak_super',
username : 'admin',
password : 'admin',
host : 'localhost',
port : 5432,
dialect : 'postgres'
})

export default sequelize

Food.ts
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../../../configs/database";

class Food extends Model {
  declare id: string;
  declare name: string;
  declare description: string;
  declare price: string;
}

Food.init(
  {
    id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
          primaryKey: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        },
        description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        },
        price: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
        allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    { modelName: "Food", sequelize: sequelize }
 );

Index.ts
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import sequelize from "./src/configs/database";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => console.log("Create Model"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

  app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     res.send("Hello World!");
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });

And This is The Result In My Terminal.

How To Fix This?, Chatgpt not give me good answer.

You have to load models on your Sequelize instance:
ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/defining-models/#initializing-the-model

@VrushabhRanpariya , btw im using sequalize v6, not v7

sorry my bad, you haven't specified so i though. \n
first of all you didn't export your FoodModel, and second id: { type: DataTypes.UUIDV4 } should be id: { type: DataTypes.UUID }  ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#uuids
\n
and also try to update price: { type:DataTypes.Number } to price: { type:DataTypes.DECIMAL } ref: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#numbers

Here you have to initialize all your models. It's up to you how you set up your Sequelize. For a basic example, you can assign it in your config file like this:
Config.ts
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import Food from "../models/Food";


const sequelize = new Sequelize({
database : 'seblak_super',
username : 'admin',
password : 'admin',
host : 'localhost',
port : 5432,
dialect : 'postgres'
});

// initialize all models
sequelize.models.Food = Food;

export default sequelize;

Wrong Datatypes for id should be UUID and price should be DECIMAL

Food.ts
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../../../configs/database";

class Food extends Model {
  declare id: string;
  declare name: string;
  declare description: string;
  declare price: string;
}

Food.init(
  {
    id: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
          primaryKey: true,
          unique: true,
        },
        name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        },
        description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        },
        price: {
        type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    { modelName: "Food", sequelize: sequelize }
 );
 export default Food;

Index.ts
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import sequelize from "./src/configs/database";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(async () => {
    await sequelize.query("SELECT 1+1");
    console.log("Connected");
    // move sync function to execute after connection got established
    sequelize
    .sync({ force: true })
    .then(() => console.log("Create Model"))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));


  app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     res.send("Hello World!");
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });


Still Not Working.

@Uletin I have slightly changed my answer on sequelize.authenticate() please look into it.
